# Radio button values not sent through email

Tags: php, html, radio-button

**EDIT:** Question has been answered. Just had to remove the form tags within the form. Thank you everybody for the heads up.

Let me try to explain this as best as I can.
I'm writing up a form that has multiple radio button groups (yes, they're all separate from each other). I'm trying to pass their values through so that they can be sent by email, but when the email is received, these values are not shown. The first group (form id="gateMats") value gets passed, but the rest of the groups don't get sent.

Here is the html code:

```
<form id="validGate" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validating(this)" action="quotationForm.php">
          <table width="730" style="margin: auto";>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><b>*</b>Gate Material: </td>
                <td><form id="gateMats" action="" onclick="return validateGateMats()">
                      <input name="material" type="radio" value="Aluminum" id="aluminum"> Aluminum &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input name="material" type="radio" value="Stainless Steel" id="stainlessSteel"> Stainless Steel</input>
                    </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Hoist Requirements: </td>
                <td><form id="gateHoistReq" action="">
                      <input name="hoiReq" type="radio" value="Manual"  id="manual" onclick="hoist(this)"> Manual &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input name="hoiReq" type="radio" value="Electric" id="electric" onclick="hoist(this)"> Electric</input>
                    </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="hoistType" style="display: none;">
                <td align="right">Hoist Type: </td>
                <td><form id="gateHostTy" action="">
                      <input type="radio" name="hoiTyp" id="handwheel" value="Handwheel"> Handwheel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input type="radio" name="hoiTyp" id="gearbox" value="90 Degree Gearbox"> 90&deg; Gearbox</input>
                    </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><p>
                  </p></td>
                <td><p>
                  </p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Stem Cover: </td>
                <td><form id="gateStemCo" action="">
                      <input type="radio" value="Clear Plastic" name="stCov" id="clearPlastic"> Clear Plastic &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input type="radio" value="Metal" name="stCov" id="metal"> Metal</input>
                    </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">Type of Stem: </td>
                <td><form id="gateStemTy" action="">
                      <input type="radio" value="Rising Stem" name="stType" id="RisingStem">Rising Stem &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input type="radio" value="Non-Rising Stem" name="stType" id="nonRisingStem">Non-Rising Stem &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
                      <input type="radio" value="Downard Opening(Weir)" name="stType" id="downwardOpening">Downward Opening (Weir)</input>
                    </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
</tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

And here's the php code:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
//Variables.
$user_gateMat = $_REQUEST['material'];
$hoiReq = $_REQUEST['hoiReq'];
$hoiTy = $_REQUEST['hoiTyp'];
$stCov = $_REQUEST['stCov'];
$stTy = $_REQUEST['stType'];

//Body of the email to be sent.
$body_mail = "Gate Details:

Gate material type: $user_gateMat

Hoist required: $hoiReq
Hoist type: $hoiTy
Stem cover: $stCov
Stem type: $stTy

//Everything okay? send the e-mail.
mail("alavarrandomity@gmail.com",'Gate Style',"$body_mail","from:SynTum");
    echo "Your email was sent! Thank you.";
}
?>
```

I have a basic grasp of php and after having seen this code for approximately 2-3 hours straight, it's become hard to tell what's the problem.

Comment: `<form>` inside a `<form>` is an invalid markup.

Comment: ah, I'll get that fixed

Comment: You can't have a `form` element in another `form` element. I suggest you edit your code and take away irrelevant codes

Comment: Create a ***single*** `form` and you may get lucky..

Comment: I took out the form tags in the code and it worked. Using multiple forms like that was pretty ridiculous and newbish of me. Thanks for the heads up, everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

(1) As mulder points out, you cannot have `<form>`s inside a `<form>`

(2) Swap the inner forms for divs.

(3) In `quotationForm.php`, instead of going straight to email, first make it print the received data to screen (i.e. build a q & d page where the received data is displayed in DIVs or input elements or whatever).

(4) You forgot to close the `$body` variable.